# Why does a function has so different performance timing?

Tags: c++, performance, timing

I'm learning C++. While solving Leetcode 0009, I wanted to time the function. For 4 different inputs I got the following results consistently:

```
1
time: 8993
0
time: 88
0
time: 1374
1
time: 1199
```

My question is why is it taking so long for the first run but not the others? And any other feedback is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
//leetcode 0009. Palindrome Number
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

bool isPalindrome(int x) {
    if (x < 0) return false;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    std::string str;
    ss >> str;

    int len = str.length();

    for (int i=0; i<len/2; i++) {
        if (str[i] != str[len-i-1])  {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}    

void timeit (bool (*f)(int), int x) {
    auto s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto res = f(x);
    auto e = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(e - s);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << "time: " << duration.count() << std::endl; //true

}

int main() {
    timeit(isPalindrome, 121);
    timeit(isPalindrome, -121);
    timeit(isPalindrome, 10);
    timeit(isPalindrome, 1001);
}
```

Comment: You are timing performance of `std::cout`, not of your function.

Comment: You should measure only the call `f(x)` without the io.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. To be more correct, OP is timing the performance of `std::cout` **and** his function.

Comment: You may be surprised to discover there isn't a tremendous difference either way. It is significant the *first* one *not* the trivial bale-case is always the *significantly* slowest, even with the IO on `std::cout` removed from the measurement. [Example here](https://godbolt.org/z/dTndhbTvK).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I deleted the cout, and just running f(x). I got these results: 10904, 84, 1379, 1121. There is still a difference of one magnitude.

Comment: The first time the function runs it needs to be loaded into cache.  Subsequent runs it's already there.

Comment: @WhozCraig what do you think is the underlying reason for that difference?

Comment: If you put them in a different order, or even if you just run the same one multiple times it gets faster after the first. If a stringstream conversion is performed before the first test it also gets faster. It would seem there's something that takes some time the first time a stringstream is used. https://godbolt.org/z/76ejWsEvT

Comment: There are various caches that need to be primed and static objects that need to be initialised by the library. Also, first calls to functions that sit in shared objects are often slower.

Comment: @Kolom The reason is that at first execution, you have a "cold cache", a "cold branch predictor", and some others things. After the first usage, the function is already stored in the cache (which extremely fast) and ready to use, the branch predictors already have some data to improve their predictions from, etc... There may be other reasons

Comment: Side note: `auto s = std::to_string(s);` would be much more elegant conversion – and I'd even assume it to be more efficient, though cannot prove...

Comment: `auto str = std::to_string(x);` isn't just more elegant; it's going to be raging faster compared to slurping all that string stream code, I suspect.

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks for suggestion. It definitely look more elegant. I'm still at my infancy with C++.

Comment: Hm... Just to annoy you – if I were leetcode – I'd provide a test case with exactly 2.147.483.648 characters ;)

Comment: To avoid the function loading problem you might duplicate the very first test case (i.e. have 121 twice) – you should notice the same difference even on identical input.

Comment: @WhozCraig wow... it's actually 5x faster.

Comment: @Aconcagua, :) now you sounded like a hiring technical manager, lol.

Comment: @Kolom Ah, well, but have you noticed what I'd be going to provoke with?

Comment: @Aconcagua isn't that overflow for int32?

Comment: Exactly ;) Correct type actually would be `size_t`, which is what `std::string::length` returns as well, though you might get away with if they don't want to probe that. Choosing too small data types can be fatal, though, famous example for (then, at least, you might be too young to remember...) is windows 95 crashing after 49 days and 17 hours running continiuously (though there an unsigned type was too small...).

Comment: @Aconcagua You know I did actually heard about windows crashing after some time. I read it somewhere. Now you mentioned it in that context makes more sense. Really thought provoking. Thanks.

Comment: @Aconcagua In leetcode it's always limited to 32bit. They have tons of questions where you are supposed to return an index into the input (or a vector of indexes) as int too.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Hm... – I wouldn't care about that and still provide `size_t` (or `ssize_t, if negative indices serve as sentinels for not found values...)` – unless compilation failing forces me to do differently (in the vector case). However that reveals leetcode's limited value in learning a language correctly...

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed. Frequently you can't solve leetcode problems correctly because their test framework then fails to compile.

Comment: You should test if an integer is a palindrome _without_ converting it to a string. The conversion takes a long time, requiring heap memory allocation etc. Stick to first principles, treat everything as integers, and think about how to get the digits from an integer without using any library function (and without using string). I leave that as an exercise. If you do it, you'll find your algorithms will be _much_ faster.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, thanks for the advice. I melted my brain to find out a solution without any conversions, just using ints, but could not find one. Then I came up with that one. After submitting I checked the discussion page. People mostly do the a lot of division and multiplication for solution. At that point I'm not sure which one is more expensive: doing string conversion or doing a lot of mul/div.

Comment: @hyde Just deleted the cout part which seems to confuse people. The core of the problem is not changed though.

Comment: @hyde I updated those as well.

Comment: Cool. Then one thing you could test is, add extra call to fill the caches etc, like this: `....{ f(x); auto s = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); ...`. That might, or might not, get rid of the strange timings. If the strange timings remain, then that's something worth looking into.

Comment: @Kolom _"I'm not sure which one is more expensive: doing string conversion or doing a lot of mul/div"_ - the string conversion is more expensive, because the line `ss << x;` in your code calls a function in the Standard Library which itself does a lot of mul/div.

Comment: Properly written benchmark looks fine: https://quick-bench.com/q/hzpkIuubesZxNReH8yE5WC2cCNM

Comment: And two alternative implementations: https://quick-bench.com/q/lR2MPyLcplEz4muNWHksVXq5_bo

Comment: @MarekR, thanks for the benchmarks. They are really eye opening. I'm new to C++ and I'm not particularly proud of using stringstream initially. It should be std::to_string, from the outset. But your ToChar benchmark result looks even faster than the std::to_string implementation on my computer, which is another interesting point for me. Anyway, on benchmarks, it seems that, there is not a big difference between cases. Do you also think that difference on my computer is because of caching?

Comment: Writing a good benchmark is hard even when this library is used. There are many silent traps which can cause invalid measurements. Without a library it is even harder. I think problem is time resolution. Google benchmark is rerunning same code multiple times to get good statistical confidence. For such small snappy function it will be in scale of couple thousands repeats. That is why this page is so slow, why you run benchmark yourself. Each test is run some may times that it cost time.

Comment: @MarekR yeah definitely. I come to believe that benchmarking is almost an art as much as a technical skill. It's not enough to know what your gonna do but you also need have a sense of philosophy, I guess.